# How to set AccessControlProfile on an entry using Kaltura API?

Tags: kaltura

I am uploading video entries through Kaltura Contribution Widget. I would like to allow users to select length of the free preview that will be shown for users who don't have rights to see entire video. I wanted to implement that by creating different AccessControlProfiles (with different preview lengths) and then assigning profile to uploaded video after user selects preview length.

Is there a way to assign access control profile using API? I looked through the docs but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to proxy the api since your users that make upload contributions ( of course ) won't be able to modify the profile. Probably easiest to have a few access control profiles for given times 5, 10, 15, etc. second previews.

The api for access controls is applied on a per entry basis. You can "add" new profiles with: http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/index.php?service=accessControlProfile

you can then assign an entry a base access control id from the baseEntry service:
http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/index.php?service=baseEntry&action=update
by populating field: 
baseEntry:accessControlId

Hope that helps.